# Indexing Optimisation: Do Simple products need to be categorised?

Tags: magento2, category-products, indexing, simple-product

Magento 2.4.6

We're having issues with our indexing and are looking to optimise.

We use Configurable products with Simple products as the variations. There are approx 200k simple products across approx 10k configurables.

Configurable products are all categorised, obviously. Our Simple products are also categorised...

But do we need to categorise Simple products?
Would removing the categorisation improve indexing efficiency?

Thanks